# Git: I forgot to do an initial commit of generated code; is this a job for rebase?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I put together a small Rails 3 app to demonstrate how it could be used with a library I'm working on. After running `rails new` I made a few changes to the Gemfile, config, and a few classes. Then I committed to git.

What I should have done was commit the initially generated structure and then my changes so that I could get a good diff of the minimal setup for this library.

Before I go through all of the steps of setting this all up again (probably like 30min, but possibly error inducing), I was wondering: is it possible to do another `rails new`, commit that, and then rebase the existing commit onto that, producing a commit with just the changes I made earlier (i.e. minus the `rails new` generated structure)?

If I understand how git works correctly, this seems doable, but it's not something I'm sure I know how to do with git's commands.

Answer (score 2):

After your initial commit, try the following:

```
git checkout -b temp
<do the rails new>
git add .
git commit --amend
git rebase --root --onto temp master
<resolve conflicts and git add and git rebase --continue>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, since your repo is so new/simple, the easiest thing to do would be to just create a new repo, do the `rails new` there, and then copy your changes over:

```
mkdir tmp; cd tmp; git init; rails new my_app; git add .;
git commit -m 'Initial commit of rails new'
rm -Rf ~/my_app/.git
cp -R ~/my_app/* ./
git add .
git commit -m 'Set up some settings in Gemfile, config, etc'
```

Git works off file contents (SHA1 hash), so this approach is totally valid.

I'm sure there is a semi-complicated way to do it within your existing repo, possibly by creating a new temporary branch, `git rebase --onto`, and then using `git filter-branch` to extract the temp branch into a new git repo... but why bother when your history is so simple? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I generally use branches for this sort of thing. Make a new empty branch, do your rails new in it, commit it - then merge the original branch on top of it.

Comment: This won't work; the parent of the branch will be the modified project. There will be nothing to merge.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether your repo is public.  Your proposed rebase will completely rewrite the history of the repository.  If this is still a private repo you will naturally fix your trunk and any branches with rebases and eventually a `git gc` will remove the old history.  If others have cloned your existing work and committed any of their own changes on top of it this history rewrite will be confusing and annoying to them.

I have never replaced the *first* revision before like you propose.  You might get better results by committing the new base revision and then using `git filter-branch` to reset the parent of the old first revision to the new first revision.  The algorithm of `git rebase` may not cope with your situation.  There's an example in `git help filter-branch`.

Comment: If some part of my answer is inaccurate tell me so I can learn something!